# How can python version installed on Redhat can be different from the version that application uses?

Tags: python, linux, version

When I type "python" in command line, it says:

```
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Dec 11 2006, 11:39:03) 
[GCC 4.1.1 20061130 (Red Hat 4.1.1-43)] on linux2
```

But I have an application that uses Python 2.7 on the same machine. How come this application is using python 2.6.5 although shell writes "2.4.3" when I type "python"?

Comment: Unfortunately, this problem isn't suited too well for SO. Although the question of _How can the Python version be different_ has been answered by @kindall, solving your actual problem will require a lot of back and forth communication. Especially because you want to install `numpy` and `matplotlib`, which, if I remember correctly, require C modules to be compiled for the correct interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's using some other Python binary, possibly one it installed. This may or may not be easily accessible to you without changing your path variable.

For example, the company I work for (Tecplot) ships a complete Python distribution with our flagship product (Tecplot 360), because of all the support headaches involved in trying to let users use whatever version of Python is installed on their machine. Worse, their machine may be locked down and they might not even be able to choose what version of Python they use. By providing our own Python binaries, we know what version the customer will be using, and we can test that it works before shipping.

If you dig around in the application's install directory, you can probably find out where they stashed their Python executable. Most likely it can be run without the application if you know where it is, and you can probably install additional modules there if you can find a `site-packages` directory (and have appropriate permissions). Try doing `echo $path` from a shell opened up from the application, if that's possible, to get a list of the directories you should look in, or in Python, do `import sys; print sys.executable`.

Comment: Yes, I can start an xterm within the application. When I type "python" in that xterm, it says: "Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Sep 27 2010, 19:19:43)". When I start xterm from Redhat desktop and type "python" there, it says: "Python 2.4.3 (#1, Dec 11 2006, 11:39:03)"

Comment: I want to install numpy and matploblib packages. I have no idea how to install them. How will that application recognize numpy and matploblib libraries?

Comment: Updated with some additional info on that topic.

Comment: @alwbtc If it says "Python 2.6.5", where do you get the Python 2.7 from?

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple versions of python installed on your machine. Try and run the following code snippet in the two environments to see where the two different python environments are installed on your system.

```
import re
print re.__file__
```

Comment: Instead of looking at some random module's `__file__` attribute, I'd use `sys.executable` to get the path to the interpreter actually being used. If that's not enough, inspecting `sys.path` will show the search paths used for that interpreter.